# How can I mark all triads of a specific type (e.g. 030T) in a graph?

Tags: python, igraph, sna

I have a dataframe df with:

```
Source, Target
aaaa, bbbb
aaaa, cccc
aaaa, dddd
bbbb, cccc
cccc, dddd
```

and so on.

File "total_edges.csv" (71kb): https://uni-duisburg-essen.sciebo.de/s/WLDD4ytkjekVcIL

I get a graph object and, according to the github issue tracker (https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/253) the triad nodes/edges but it fails:

```
import pandas as pd
import igraph as ig

df_edges = pd.read_csv("total_edges.csv")

g = ig.Graph.TupleList(df_edges.itertuples(index=False), directed=True)
tc = g.triad_census()
ffl = ig.Graph.Formula("A --> B --> C, A --> C")
result = g.get_subisomorphisms_lad(ffl, induced=True)
print(result)
```

Error message (VM with updated Pop_OS x64, Python 3.7.5):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "count_triads.py", line 20, in <module>
    ffl = ig.Graph.Formula("A --> B --> C, A --> C")
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/igraph/formula.py", line 209, in construct_graph_from_formula
    for start_names, end_names, arrowheads in generate_edges(part):
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/igraph/formula.py", line 90, in generate_edges
    raise SyntaxError(msg)
SyntaxError: invalid token found in edge specification: A --> B --> C
```

How can I mark all nodes in that graph with the triad value (A, B, C, None) for triad type 030T so that I can filter/plot triads and non-triads differently?

Comment: "import igraph", Installation via "pip install python-igraph".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the error, it looks like you're hit by an issue similar to this [issue in the formula parser](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/235).

Trying to apply the recent [changes](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/commits/master/igraph/formula.py) or [installing the development version of python-igraph](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph#compiling-the-development-version) may help here.

Comment: That's the solution. "sudo pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph.git" on a Linux machine (real or VM) gives the latest python-igraph dev version with all bugfixes.

Comment: The result in the form of [
    [23, 32, 33],
    [23, 33, 34],
    [24, 33, 190],
    [24, 33, 86]] stands for A, B ,C in triad 030T. The numbers map to the igraph node/vertex ids which one gets via "for idx, node in enumerate(g.vs):
    print(str(idx) + "," + node["name"])". Then mapping the triad ids to the node ids to get a list with all nodes that are part of a triad.

Comment: After updating my igraph version on Windows it works there as well, seems the bugfix went upstream so no need for a Linux VM anymore.